# Android: If multiple apps on the same device use the same SDK, do they use the same instance of the sdk?

Tags: java, android, sdk

I am working on an SDK in which when the app using the sdk sends a request to the sdk i create a request ID and when the response comes back i ensure check the id of the response as well to ensure that the request id and response id match.

My assumption is that if there are multiple apps on the same device which use the same sdk. If they all send a request, do all the apps use their own separate instance of the sdk? or do they share the some common instance of the sdk?

if they have their own instances, then each instance would only store the request id of the app that called it, but if they all shared the same instance of the sdk, then the sdk would have to manage multiple request ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the same library (or SDK) in multiple apps they each get their own copy.  Even if you share a dynamically linked library like a .so, they'd each get their own copy in memory.  To share a single instance you'd actually need to jump through hoops and have them all connect to the same publicly exported Service.  So you can get that if you really want it, but its not the default behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Yes they use same instance of that sdk.There are many apps made for running muliple apps on same sdk,you can check out this link
http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/03/18/app-cloner-creates-multiple-instances-of-the-same-app-on-your-phone/

Comment: so while store the request id, I should store it with a key like - requestid-applicationId, so that each application knows which request id to look at.
Thanks a lot :)